# XOR in java is not providing binary values

Tags: java

This is my code . I want a binary value for c ,but my output is 294977 . How to xor this?

```
public class Dumm {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        int a = 01101010;
        int b = 00001111;
        int c = a ^ b;
        System.out.print(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please only post well-formatted code. I've formatted your code for you this time, but in the future we'd appreciate your doing this for us.

Comment: Note that a and b are not binary numbers as you assume them to be. They're actually *octal*.

Comment: How to get binary values for a and b?

Comment: use binary literals: `0b01101010`

Comment: But after making a value as 0x01101010 and b value as 0x00001111 i get the output for c as 17826049

Comment: Then you must print it out in a binary format.

Comment: I am getting error if i make a as ob01101010 and i changed integer b to integer f as b00001111 ;

Comment: you can still use 'b' as a variable name, it has nothing to do with 'b' being used in 0b001... it is a notation, used to represent number in bases other than decimal.

Comment: But i m getting this error Dumm.java:5:';' expected int a=0b1101010 . It points to b using this ^ and the same error in int b also

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take a and b as binary value then start with "0b".
for print binary value use "Integer.toBinaryString()" method.
Try this:

```
 public static void main(String [] args)
 {
 int a = 0b1101010;
 int b = 0b0001111;
 int c = a ^ b;
 System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(c));
 }
```

Comment: But i m getting this error Dumm.java:5:';' expected int a=0b1101010 . It points to b using this ^  and the same error in int b also

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to treat your numbers as binary, you have to start numbers with `0b`.
You have prepended o(English Alphabet) instead of 0(Zero).

```
        int a = 0b01101010;
        int b = 0b00001111;
        int c = a ^ b;
        System.out.print(Integer.toBinaryString(c));
```

Comment: System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(c)) not System.out.print(c)